# function to create a .dat file only if it doesn't exist in C?

Tags: c

I have this code, I need the function to only create the file if it doesn't exist,
if the file already exists it should not do anything.

The function `fill_blank_highscore()` is the one that creates the file,
if the file does not exist, this code creates it but the program closes and I have to run it a second time

```
void create_highscore_dat(){
    FILE* highscore;
    highscore = fopen("highscore.dat", "r");    
    if(highscore == NULL) {
        fill_blank_highscore();
    }
    if(highscore == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(highscore);
}
```

Comment: To me this seems like an XY problem. Don't clutter a users harddrive with empty/blank files. Just create the highscore file the first time you need to store an entry, and treat a missing highscore file as empty highscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not report an error when `highscore == NULL` -- that's the desired case. It should report an error if opening the file is successful, since that means it already exists.

```
void create_highscore_dat(){
    FILE* highscore;
    highscore = fopen("highscore.dat", "r");    
    if(highscore == NULL) { // file doesn't exist, create it
        fill_blank_highscore();
    } else { // file already exists, abort
        fclose(highscore);
        printf("highscore.dat already exists, not saving.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I question the use of `exit()` at all.  It might make sense if `fopen()` actually failed due to a real fatal failure, like Access Denied, etc, or if `fill_blank_highscore()` failed to create the new file. But why use `exit()` for a recoverable error like File Exists?

Comment: Good point. I've replaced it with printing an error message.

Comment: I put the second if in case the first if did not create the file (either due to very unlikely cases such as there was no memory). I see that it was not necessary, (I'm learning to program)

Comment: Creating the file in `fill_blank_highscore()` doesn't affect the variables in this function. That variable still has the result of this `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling `exit()` to terminate the process if `fopen()` is not able to open an existing file. Simply get rid of `exit()` if you don't want the program to terminate if a new file has to be created.

If you open the file with `fopen()` in `"a"` mode, it will create a new file if one does not already exist, otherwise it will open the existing file and seek to the end of the file, leaving existing data intact.  So, for example, if `fopen()` is successful, and then `ftell()`/`fgetpos()` says the file is empty, fill the file with your default data as needed before closing the file.

```c
int fill_blank_highscore(FILE* highscore)
{
    // write to file as needed...
    return ...; // 0 on success, < 0 on failure...
}

void create_highscore_dat(){
    FILE* highscore = fopen("highscore.dat", "a");
    if (highscore != NULL) {
        long pos = ftell(highscore);
        if (pos == 0) {
            if (fill_blank_highscore(highscore) < 0) {
                pos = -1L;
            }
        }
        fclose(highscore);
        if (pos != -1L) return;
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment, I think this is an XY problem. But if you really want open to fail when the file already exists, you could use the lower level `open` function rather than `fopen`:

```
int fd = open("highscore.dat", O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR,
                               S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP);
if (fd == -1 && errno == EEXIST)
  {
    /* File already exist */
  }
else if (fd == -1)
  {
     /* 
       File failed to open for other reasons (permissions, IO-error, etc)
     */
     perror("Failed to create highscore file");
  }
else
  {
     /* do something with file */
  }
```

`O_CREAT` allows the file to be created, and `O_EXCL` makes `open` fail if the file already exist. `O_RDWR` makes the fildescriptor `fd` usable for both read and writes. `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP` sets the file permissions on disk to read/write for both user and group.

Flags and mode bits should be adapted to specific use case, see `man open`.

The filedescriptor `fd` can be turned into a `FILE *` if you prefer to use the higher level stream-based functions for IO. (as you should when possible):

```
 else
  {
     /* do something with file */
     FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "r+");
     if (!f)
       {
          close(fd);
          perror("Failed to create file stream");
       }
     else
       {
         /* Work with `f` */
         fill_blank_highscore(f);

         fclose(f);  /* `f` owns `fd`, so this will also close `fd` */
       }
  }
```